# HTTPS Redirect and Subdomains NGINX

Tags: nginx, ssl, web-server, linux-networking, https

I have two subdomains on my website all serving web apps and a website running on the domain (and `www.`) itself; these are:

`gitea.mywebsite.co.uk` - running on `:3000`

and

`mail.mywebsite.co.uk` - not yet running

Both of these are configured with DNS `CName` entries pointing them to `mywebsite.co.uk` and I've checked that these have in-fact propegated.

I want to serve `HTTPS` exclusively and consequently have acquired and installed `SSL Certificates` for both subdomains and the domain as a whole (I can't afford any of these fancy wildcard certificates).

In order to achieve this, I've set up `nginx` to listen on `:80` and redirect ALL incoming `HTTP` traffic to `HTTPS` as such (I'll implement `HSTS` once I have everything up and running):

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name _;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

This seems to work okay, regardless of what subdomain I enter, I see the browser redirect it to the `HTTPS` equivalent.

So the issue appears to occur somewhere during the `reverse proxy` stage of the configuration. I want all requests made to `gitea.mywbsite.co.uk` to be passed to `:3000` to handle. I am achieving this like such:

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name gitea.mywebsite.co.uk;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/gitea.mywebsite.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/gitea.mywebsite.key;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        location / {
                proxy_pass https://localhost:3000/;
        }
}
```

However, whenever I attempt to access this I am greeted by a standard browser "Can't connect" error (note, this isn't the SSL error page).

I can connect to the webapp just fine by loading `mywebsite.co.uk:3000` directly so that is definitely running. I've also double-checked the `symlink` to `sites-enabled`, restarted `nginx` and still no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;`

Comment: this doesn't make any difference @RichardSmith

Comment: Check the configuration with `nginx -T`

Comment: I get the following:

nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok

nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

And then an echo of my `nginx.conf` were you wanting me to check something specific?

Comment: If `nginx` is listening on port 443, but the browser cannot connect - is there a firewall in-between?

Comment: I've just ran `netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN` and it actually appears that `nginx` isn't listening on any ports... Which is weird. Oops... See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that the problem was one borne of my own laziness.

When I symlinked the server blocks I did so like this:

`ln -s ./gitea ../sites-enabled/gitea`

From within the `sites-available` directory.

It would appear that this sort of shorthand doesn't work whilst creating symlinks. So whilst it appeared that the link had been created successfully, the links were actually broken. As soon as I recreated the full paths using the below command it worked just fine.

`ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/gitea /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/gitea`

Thanks Richard Smith for your help!

Comment: That's because relative symbolic links are relative to the location of the symbolic link. You could have created a symbolic link in sites enabled like so `ln -s ../sites-available/gitea /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/gitea`. This would work from anywhere on the system since all it creates is essentially a file that says look in `../sites-available/gitea` relative to the link location.